# Nuxt 3 useFetch isn't including the Cookie header in the request

Tags: javascript, fetch, cross-browser, nuxtjs3

I'm using Nuxt 3 to make an external request to another server: I'm trying to pass a cookie variable in the header, but examining the network request, it's not present. Here is my composable:

```
const {data, error} = await useFetch("https://eo761aoiqhvo0xx.m.pipedream.net", {
    query: {
        origin: "example",
        qty: "1",
        sku: product.sku
    },
    onRequest({request, options}) {
        options.query = options.query || {}
        options.headers = options.headers || {}

        if (cart_session.value && cart_session.value.session) {
            options.headers["Cookie"] = `${config.public.cart_session.name}=${cart_session.value.session};`
        }

       console.log("[fetch request]", request, options)
    },
    onRequestError({request, options, error}) {
        // Log error
        console.log("[fetch request error]", request, error)
    },
    onResponse({request, response, options}) {
        console.log("[fetch response]", request, response._data, options)
        // cart_session.value = response._data
    },
    onResponseError({request, response, options}) {
        // Log error
        console.log("[fetch response error]", request, response.status, response.body)
    }
})
```

I have some login in place to check if the variable is set, which it is. I've also tried passing the Cookie parameter in the header array without any luck. Nuxt's documentation seems a bit limited so I'm not sure if it's even possible through their fetch composable. If not, I'm open to another solution.

I've tried passing the cookie header in multiple ways without any luck. I've also tried making a /server/api/ function without luck.

Comment: I'm not sure if it works with `useFetch` but I know it works with `$fetch`: you can add `credentials: 'include'` property to the request object. Please try and let me know, so I will write a proper answer.

Comment: By reading the `useFetch` documentation, I see that it is a wrapper around `$fetch`, so the previous suggest should definitely work. At least it solved the issue in one of my project.

Comment: I have the same problem - did you solve this, and how? 

Answer (score 3):

As per the [documentation](https://nuxt.com/docs/getting-started/data-fetching#pass-client-headers-to-the-api), the cookie headers must be explicitly passed to the `useFetch` call:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
const headers = useRequestHeaders(['cookie'])

const { data } = await useFetch('/api/me', { headers })
</script>
```

Comment: This is only needed for server side requests